# writing to external program through pipe (C)

Tags: c, pipe, ipc

I wanted to use external program to process data in memory. Like external compressor, encoder, anything to process my data and get the result. I read a lot about pipes and it still din't work. So I ended up with simple program that tries to write to external program through pipe like this, letting it to print to stdout:

```
                                                     stdout
             (w) pipeA (r)          $prog            +---+
             +-----------+       /~~~~~~~~~~~\       |{1}|
             |[1]     [0]| ----> |{0}     {1}| ----> |   |
        +~~> +-----------+       \~~~~~~~~~~~/       |   |
        |                                            +---+
        |
       +-+
 write() |
       +-+
```

And I still got nowhere.
My code goes like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(void)
{
    int pipA[2];
    int pid;
    char buf_IN[32] = "Hello pipe!\n";
    ssize_t n_written;

    if ((pipe(pipA) == -1))    {
        perror("pipe failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)    {
        perror("fork failed");
        exit(2);
    }
    /*****************************/

    if (pid == 0)
        { /* in child */
        dup2(0, pipA[0]);   // pipA[read(0)-end]->$prog[write{0}-end]
        close(pipA[1]);   // $prog won't write to this pipe(A)
        // external ``$prog''ram
        execlp("wc", "wc", (char *) 0);   // out should be: '      1       2      12'
        //execlp("base64", "base64", (char *) 0);   // out should be: 'SGVsbG8gcGlwZSEK'

        ;///if we're here something went wrong
        perror("execlp() @child failed");
        exit(3);
        }

    else
        { /* in parent */
        //dup2(pipA[1], 0);  // STDIN -> pipA // that supposed to connect STDIN->pipA; just in case I needed it
        close(pipA[0]);  // we won't read it, let $prog write to stdout
        //perror("execlp() @parent failed");
        //exit(4);
        n_written = write(pipA[1], buf_IN, strlen(buf_IN));
        close(pipA[1]);  // I guess this will close the pipe and send child EOF

        // base64: read error: Input/output error
        // wc: 'standard input': Input/output error
        //      0       0       0
        }

return 0;
}
```

Comments show what I'm doing. I have to admit I don't get these dup()s in pipes and that's what I think is causing a problem here but don't know.
Can you help with this, seemingly simple problem? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Diagnosis

You have the arguments to `dup2()` back-to-front.  You need:

```
dup2(pipA[0], 0);
```

#### Closing file descriptors

You are not closing enough file descriptors in the child:

---

**Rule of thumb**: If you
[`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)
one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the
original file descriptors returned by
[`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)
as soon as possible.
In particular, you should close them before using any of the
[`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html)
family of functions.

The rule also applies if you duplicate the descriptors with either
[`dup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html)
or
[`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html)
with `F_DUPFD`

---

#### Prescription

You have some unused defines and unused variables in your code, too.  Shorn of all your comments (but with a few of mine to explain what's happening) and with appropriate fixes in place, I end up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pipA[2];
    int pid;
    char buf_IN[32] = "Hello pipe!\n";
    ssize_t n_written;

    if ((pipe(pipA) == -1))
    {
        perror("pipe failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("fork failed");
        exit(2);
    }

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        /* Child: Connect pipA[0] (read) to standard input 0 */
        dup2(pipA[0], 0);
        close(pipA[1]);  /* Close write end of pipe */
        close(pipA[0]);  /* Close read  end of pipe */
        execlp("wc", "wc", (char *)0);
        perror("execlp() @child failed");
        exit(3);
    }
    else
    {
        close(pipA[0]);  /* Close read end of pipe */
        n_written = write(pipA[1], buf_IN, strlen(buf_IN));
        if (n_written != (ssize_t)strlen(buf_IN))
        {
            perror("short write");
            exit(4);
        }
        close(pipA[1]);  /* Close write end of pipe — EOF for child */
    }

    /* Optionally wait for child to die before exiting */
    // #include <sys/wait.h>  // With other #include lines
    // int corpse;
    // int status;
    // while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
    //     printf("Child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);

    return 0;
}
```

When run, that produces:

```
       1       2      12
```

That looks about right.

Without the `wait()` loop, it is possible that you'll see the output from `wc` after the prompt from the shell (so it might look as if the program is waiting for input from you, but in fact, it will be the shell waiting for input); with the waiting loop, you'll get proper separation of output from the shell prompt.  You don't have to print anything in the body of the loop, but it is reassuring to do so.

Comment: Thanks, that was quick.
I will try to digest it and get dup2() with it.

PS. I have edited out unused variables
PPS. Just tested your program and it still waits for <enter>. What does it mean really? Shouldn't return to terminal instead of waiting to enter data from user?

Comment: Lemme double check, but I believe that if you copy’n’paste the code in my answer, it will give you the output from `wc` without any user interaction.  One of the things that pointed me to the mis-written `dup2()` was that `wc` didn’t terminate.

Comment: It does give the answer but program still waits of user's input.
--
Btw. can you comment those dup2()s and close()s so one knows what they do? Reason I'm asking is I clearly didn't understand dup2() and still have doubts.

Am I right about closing pipA[] ends in parent?

Is it right to say that `dup2(pipA[0], 0);` connects pipA[0]--->{0} ?

And does pipA[0] become {0} or {0} becomes pipA[0]?

Comment: I've added some notes (and commented out code) to my answer.  When the child calls `dup2(pipA[0], 0)`, then after the call completes, both `pipA[0]` and `0` refer to the same open file description as `pipA[0]` did before the call (even though they are two different open file descriptors — beware careful use of 'description' vs 'descriptor'). When you subsequently close `pipA[0]`, only standard input refers to the read end of the pipe (which is what you want). Note that the parent process also has an open file descriptor that refers to the same open file description — until it closes `pipA[0]`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

To not make duplicates, nor to play expert in unfamiliar field I post it as answer.

I finished the task

```
                 (w) pipeA (r)            child            (w) pipeB (r)
                 +-----------+       /~~~~~~~~~~~~~\       +-----------+
            +~~~>|[1]     [0]| ----> |{0} $prog {1}| ----> |[1]     [0]| ~~~+
            |    +-----------+       \~~~~~~~~~~~~~/       +-----------+    |
            |                                                               \/
           +-+                                                             +--+
     write() |                                                             |  read()
           +-+                                                             +--+

                dup(pA[0],0)                                dup(pB[1],1)
                close(pA[1])                                close(pA[0])
                close(pA[0])                                close(pA[1])
```

with second pipe that can be read. All by analogy. If there is something major that is wrong with it or something I should be aware of, say it please.
(Sorry for python style indentations, hope you don't mind)

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

ssize_t read_whole_file(int fildes, const void *buf, size_t nbyte);

int main(void)
    {
    int pipA[2], pipB[2];
    int pid;
    char buf_IN[32] = "Hello pipe!\n";
    char buf_OUT[1024];
    char *bptr;
    ssize_t n_written, n_read = 0, a_read = 0, to_read = sizeof(buf_OUT);

    if ((pipe(pipA) == -1) || (pipe(pipB) == -1))
        {
        perror("pipe failed");
        exit(1);
        }
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        {
        perror("fork failed");
        exit(2);
        }

    if (pid == 0)
        {
        /* in child */
        dup2(pipA[0], 0);  // connect pipe A (read end/exit) to stdin (write end/input)
        close(pipA[1]);  // close unused pipe A end
        close(pipA[0]);  // close  - " - //
        ;
        dup2(pipB[1], 1);  // connect stdout (read end/output) to pipe B (write end/entry)
        close(pipB[0]);  // close unused pipe B ends
        close(pipB[1]);  // close  - " - //
        execlp("lzip", "lzip", "-c", (char *)0);
        ;
        perror("execlp() @child failed");
        exit(3);
        }
    else
        {
        /* in parent */
        close(pipA[0]);  // close pipe A read end - will only write to this one
        n_written = write(pipA[1], buf_IN, strlen(buf_IN));
        if (n_written < 0)
            perror("error: read_whole_file(pipA[1], ...) failed miserably\n");
        close(pipA[1]);  // close write end which subsequently signals EOF to child
        ;
        close(pipB[1]);  // close pipe B write end - will only read form this one
        a_read = read_whole_file(pipB[0], buf_OUT, sizeof(buf_OUT));
        if (a_read < 0)
            perror("error: read_whole_file(pipB[0], ...) failed miserably\n");
        close(pipB[0]);  // close read end after reading
        ;
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf_OUT, a_read);  // dump it to parent's stdout - equivalent of processing data received from external program/plugin
        }
    return 0;
    }

ssize_t read_whole_file(int fildes, const void *buf, size_t nbyte)  // read whole file
    {
    ssize_t n_read, a_read = 0, to_read = nbyte;
    char *bptr = (char*)buf;
    size_t BUF_SIZE = 4096;
    do
        {
        if(to_read < BUF_SIZE)
            BUF_SIZE = to_read;
        n_read = read(fildes, bptr, BUF_SIZE);
        if (n_read < 0)  // recover from temporarily failed read (got it from git wrapper)
            {
            if ((errno == EINTR) || (errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EWOULDBLOCK))
                continue;
            }
        bptr += n_read;
        to_read -= n_read;
        a_read += n_read;
        } while ((n_read>0) && (to_read>0));
    ;
    if (n_read < 0)
        a_read = n_read;
    return a_read;
    }
```

To note not so obvious - I still don't get `close(pipA[0]);` and `close(pipB[1]);` in child. Why are they not used anymore?
Also `dup2(pipB[1], 1);`, I thought it would be other way around but it didn't work so by trial end error I come with this.

Comment: In this scenario, you may get away without closing all the pipe ends in the child, but in other scenarios (e.g. 3 processes and 2 pipes, or more, or several pipes working in two directions) not closing the pipe ends may lead to processes not getting EOF when they need it because a process that has no intention of writing to the pipe still has it open for writing.  Or a process may get hung up because there's a process that has the pipe open for reading, so the system assumes it might read from it, even though it has no intention of doing so, so instead of signalling the writer, it blocks it.